# How to get label for corresponding swipe in barchart of mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, textview, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

How to get label for corresponding bar when I swipe the barchart? I have another textview outside of barchart. When I swipe mpandroidchart graph, I need to get x axis label of corresponding position and display in textview. How to do that?

I tried with this.

```
 barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            Log.i("Entry", String.valueOf(e));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

or OnChartGestureListener too, I tried but I don't know how to get the label of the corresponding bar.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know whether it is helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

In case of `OnChartValueSelectedListener`, you can do

```
barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            String value = barChart.getBarData().getXVals().get(e.getXIndex());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

In the similar way you can achieve this for other listeners too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is it possible for swipe? because i can't find how to get value in [swipe](http://paste.ofcode.org/rhE4DGP7TWDAXyfeQFEnfE)

Comment: @Shadow did you get a entry value via swipe .Let me know i need a help

Answer (score 0):

Implement `mChart.setOnChartGestureListener` method, and you will see `onChartTranslate` `Override` method.

```
mChart.getXValue(mChart.getHighestVisibleXIndex());
```

This will return you the value of the highest visible index after swipe.
Hope this answer will help you to solve your problem.